# what is the usage of PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE in pthread?

Tags: c, pthreads

I read some codes as below:

```
void
mcachefs_file_start_thread()
{
  pthread_attr_t attrs;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrs, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  pthread_create(&mcachefs_file_threadid, &attrs, mcachefs_file_thread, NULL);
}
```

Here, what is the usage of setting `attrs` as `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE`? Besides, isn't it the default attribute of a thread created by `pthead_create`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE` is the default attribute. The purpose is that it allows you to call [`pthread_join`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) on the thread, which is a function that waits until the thread finishes, and gives you return value if its main routine.

Sometimes, when you're creating a thread to do some background work, it might be a good idea to make sure it has finished before you use its results or move to something else. That's what joinable threads are for.

Comment: +1 for being accurate, though I prefer a different explanation 'it's to allow you to easily lock up your app,  allow you to continually create/terminate/destroy threads in an uncontrolled manner, allow attempts at thread micro-management that will not work, reduce overall performance and prevent your app from shutting down promptly or, indeed, at all'.

Answer (score 3):

From posix spec, the default setting of the detach state attribute in a newly initialized thread attributes object is indeed PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE.
See for instance http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate 
So you are right: the pthread_attr_setdetachstate line of code is not necessary in your code snippet.